# SymPy: How do I create symbolic lambda function?

Tags: python, sympy

For example I have this expression:

```
x = Symbol('x')
f = sin(x) * x
```

I want the following code to work:

```
>>> a = Symbol('a')
>>> f(a)
TypeError: 'Mul' object is not callable
```

I can turn this expression into a lambda function that will work with numbers:

```
>>> f = lambdify(x, f)
>>> f(10)
-5.440211108893697
```

But it is not worked for symbols:

```
>>> f = lambdify(x, f)
>>> f(a)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable sin method
```

I know about the *.subs method, but I'm interested in the this notation:

```
>>> a = Symbol('a')
>>> f(a)
```

How to do it?

Comment: `f = lambda x:sin(x)*x`

Comment: uh, is it really that simple?

Comment: Yes, it's too simple maybe … Compare `type(sin(x)*x)` with `type(lambda x:sin(x)*x)`

Comment: In your case it looks like you just want a plain Python lambda function as said above. In other contexts it can also be useful to use sympy's `Lambda` function which gives a "symbolic" function. This is used in e.g. `ImageSet`.

Comment: According to the `lambdify` docs, it converts your `sin(x)` to `np.sin(x)`.  It's that `np.sin` that can't handle the `symbol`.  It works fine with numbers and numeric arrays.  As the error says, for a non-numeric object the `numpy` code tries to do `x.sin()`.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer fully so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`.subs()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution)!

```py
>>> x, a = symbols("x a")
>>> f = sin(x) * x
>>> f
x*sin(x)
>>> f.subs(x, a)
a*sin(a)
>>> f.subs(x, parse_expr("ln(z)"))
log(z)*sin(log(z))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just learning an option, using SymPy [Lambda functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.function.Lambda)

```py
import sympy as sp
x, a = sp.symbols("x a")
f = sp.Lambda(x, sp.sin(x) * x)
print(f(1))
print(f(a))
```

```py
>>> print(f(1))
sin(1)
>>> print(f(a))
a*sin(a)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I cleaned this up a bit - please [edit] to taste if it's not right!